# Why isn't Python read() function working?

Tags: python, function

I want to write a reminder program using python. But for some reason, when I read the file it returns nothing. Here's my code,

```
print ("(1)Add something to list\n(2)Read my lists")
option = input ("Please select an option: ")
myFile = open ("Reminder.txt", "a+")
if option == '1':
    ask = input ("What do you want to remember: ")
    myFile.write (ask + "\n")
    myFile.close()
    print ("Successfully added in database")
elif option == '2':
    AllFileContents = myFile.read()
    print (AllFileContents)
else:
    print ("Please select an existing option!")
```

And this is the output I get after adding something to list(I'm using microsoft visual studio):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuS9W.png

Please help.

Comment: You are opening in `a+` mode... the cursor will be at the end of the file

Comment: It looks like you should be opening the file after you check the `option` from the user.

Comment: [the meaning of the different modes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: So, what should I do...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `seek` -

```
print ("(1)Add something to list\n(2)Read my lists")
option = input ("Please select an option: ")
myFile = open ("Reminder.txt", "a+")
if option == '1':
    ask = input ("What do you want to remember: ")
    myFile.write (ask + "\n")
    myFile.close()
    print ("Successfully added in database")
elif option == '2':
    myFile.seek(0)
    AllFileContents = myFile.read()
    print (AllFileContents)
else:
    print ("Please select an existing option!")
```

Reference - [seek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-seek-function/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20seek()%20function,or%20written%20in%20the%20file.&text=from_what%3A%20It%20defines%20point%20of%20reference.)

`seek(0)` sets the cursor back to the first part of the file , so that you can read the file from the start (basically the whole file.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the open() function without a+ mode. A+ mode puts the cursor at the end of the file.

Comment: Then what mode should I put...?

Comment: I get an error not writable

Comment: Put the `myFile = open (...)` into the `if...else...` statements, i.e., put `myFile = open ("Reminder.txt", "a+")` within the `if option == '1':` statement, and put `myFile = open ("Reminder.txt", "r")` (the `"r"` means open in "read" mode) in the `elif option == '2':` statement.